# Running an open-source project on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, coffeescript

I am trying to run [HabitRPG](https://github.com/lefnire/habitrpg) on Heroku because I don't have root access in the machines in my school's library to install the dependencies.

The [wiki](https://github.com/lefnire/habitrpg/wiki/Running-Locally) to HabitRPG gives instructions on how to run it on a localmachine, but does not talk about running it on Heroku. I understand that HabitRPG used to run on Heroku, but lefnire had to move it.

What am I facing here? How much work am I looking at to run on Heroku? Have they not given instructions to deploy it because they don't want people to? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: BIG thank you for bringing my attention to HabitRPG. It's friggin awesome! As per your question: ask on the GitHub project page.

Comment: Given that it has a `Procfile` and `package.json`, it is likely that it will just work out of the box on Heroku. Try cloning it and pushing it to a new Heroku app.